# Unable to Submit for Approval

Tags: sharing, approval-process, role-hierarchy, sharerecord

I have a custom object K__c with OWD setting Private and with Grant Access Using Hierarchies set to true.

There is a record k1 with owner u1.

u1 has role r1.

Manager of u1 is u2.

r1 reports to r2.

Role of u2 is rx.

rx doesn't belong to the r1 parent hierarchy structure.

I've created a K_share record with :

ParentId = k1

UserOrGroupId = u2

AccessLevel = Read

RowCause = Manual

Still u2 is getting insufficient privilege error while accessing k1.

I've a approval process in place, and when I try to submit for approval, it is throwing error:

> Unable to Submit for Approval

as manager of u1, i.e u2, doesn't have access to k1 by role hierarchy setting.

Is there any other way to avoid this error, without changing the role of these two users or changing the ManagerId of this user?

Please suggest.

Comment: What are profile settings for u2? does it have read access on object?

Comment: @C0DEPirate thanks... I've missed it.. Now provided Read & Edit on that profile and u2 is able to view k1... but u1 is still not able to submit for approval.

Comment: @C0DEPirate .. Also, I've this approval process without any entry criteria. That should not prevent it from getting submitted for approval. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're sharing the record based on U1 sharing it directly with U2, whom U1 reports to, NOT through the hierarchy. As I understand it, you're then expecting U2 to be able to approve the record that's been shared directly with him/her from the user that owns it. This would be ripe for "cherry picking" an approver and runs counter to Role Based approval processes.

U2 should be receiving his sharing from the User that's in the role in the hierarchy above U1. If that role doesn't exist, then you need to either create it, move U2 into that role, or move U1 into a role beneath U2. In the latter sitation, U2 can then use Role based sharing to share those records with the Role that was previously above U1.

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving it a try in this way..and will let you know the outcome.